# How were the number of rounds for different key sizes of AES selected?

Tags: aes, block-cipher

The number of AES rounds increases with the key length. Why increase the number of rounds at all, and how were these round counts chosen?

Comment: This question is related to [this one](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2593/how-were-the-aes-key-and-block-length-subsets-of-rijndael-selected).

Comment: Maybe this article provides some explanations: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/cryptanalysis/aesbc.pdf The math behind the attacks that are detailed in the paper is a bit too much for me, though.

Comment: $N_r = len(key)/4 + 6$.

Comment: Chris Smith, can you elaborate?

Comment: As to the choice for the round numbers? Have a look at this document: http://csrc.nist.gov/archive/aes/rijndael/Rijndael-ammended.pdf. Note the "Number of rounds" section under "Motivation for design choices".

Comment: Here's a semantically correct implementation I quickly whipped up which takes into account any changes that could be made to Nb or Nk which Nr is supposed to be a function of according to 2.1 Definitions: https://gist.github.com/rdev5/f95da22762771f6ed3f2

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Some quotes from [The Design of Rijndael](https://autonome-antifa.org/IMG/pdf/Rijndael.pdf) (pdf, see Section 3.5 "The Number of Rounds"):

> For Rijndael with a block length and key length of 128 bits, no shortcut attacks had been found for reduced versions with more than six rounds. We added four rounds as a security margin.

The addition of four rounds is justified by:

> Two rounds of Rijndael provide 'full diffusion' in the following
>   sense:  every state bit depends on all state bits two rounds ago, or a
>   change in  one state bit is likely to affect half of the state bits
>   after two rounds.  Adding four rounds can be seen as adding a 'full
>   diffusion step' at the  beginning and at the end of the cipher.

Regarding longer key lengths:

> For Rijndael versions with a longer key, the number of rounds was
>   raised  by one for every additional 32 bits in the cipher key.

Unfortunately no derivation of this magic 1:32 ratio is given.

Answer (score 9):

There are two reasons:

- More rounds means more security against cryptanalysis, simply, since there is more confusion and diffusion.
- For a secure block cipher, there should be no attack faster than exhaustive key search (i.e. brute force). As exhaustive key search takes a lot longer for a larger key size, a theoretical attacker can afford more work to "break" the larger cipher. Thus we also increase the round number a bit to increase the security level of our cipher accordingly.
- For a larger key size (as well as a larger block size), we need more rounds so that every key bit affects every ciphertext bit in a similar way, i.e. without measurable differences which would allow any cryptanalysis.

The 10 rounds for AES-128 seem to be about the lower level of what is (approximately) 128-bit-secure, and 10 rounds for a AES-256-like-cipher would have way below 256 bits of security.

Comment: keep in mind that while this is generally true for `good` ciphers (aes, twofish, serpent, etc) there are some attacks that will make the number of rounds a cipher has irrelevant e.g: increasing the number of rounds will not give any additional security against that attack (the slide attack being the one that comes to mind first).

Comment: @cipher: I used my moderator powers to convert your answer to a comment, as wished. Normally one needs to earn [50 reputation](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment) before being able to comment on posts other than your own (or answers to your question).

Comment: Thanks for noting the slide attack, I'll read up on it (but not today).

Comment: Is there a more technical explanation?

Comment: This is a bit more detailed in the Rijndael specification (the book one), but I don't have it on hand. Maybe someone else can give a more detailed answer here (I would certainly upvote it).