# Question about the security of Substitution-Permutation Network

Tags: des, spn

In general, we execute key-mixing, substitution and permutation sequentially in a single round in a n-round SPN, but if we execute n-round key-mixing firstly, n-round substitution secondly and n-round permutation finally, how is the security of this modified SPN?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Increase number of rounds for SPN and Feistel ciphers](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/5050/increase-number-of-rounds-for-spn-and-feistel-ciphers)

Comment: @e-sushi Disagree with the duplicate vote as suggested duplicate is about increasing the number of permutations (rounds) whereas this question is about changing the order of substitutions and permutations.

Answer (score 2):

I think this would effectively make your cipher a single round.

Key mixing is usually an XOR operation of the round key on the current state. XORing all of the round keys at once is effectively only xoring a single key.

If you have an $n\times n$ bit s-box $s(x)$ (e.g. [Rijndael's sbox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rijndael_S-box)), then $s(s(x))$ is just another sbox which can be expressed as a lookup table.

The same logic applies to the permutation. If you have a permutation $p(x)$ then $p(p(x))$ is itself a permutation.