# does increasing the number of rounds in feistel increase the security

Tags: encryption, des, feistel-network

In feistel cipher , does it matter that number of rounds ? is using more rounds will give the best result?
or it's all about the key size ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Increase number of rounds for SPN and Feistel ciphers](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/5050/increase-number-of-rounds-for-spn-and-feistel-ciphers). Simply it increases the attack times, except the upper bound = brute force.

Comment: yes increasing the rounds doesn't mean increasing security but why ?

Comment: Read the answer, and note that the provided security by any cipher cannot exceed the key search by brute-force.