# AES encryption algorithm

Tags: aes, algorithm-design

What is the amount of decrease in the probability of decrypting a data encrypted using an AES algorithm? (That is by introducing each round out of ten whole rounds, how the probability of decryption is reduced?)

Comment: Why are you asking the same question twice?

Comment: Sorry, your question as it is is not understandable. Could you try to reword it so it makes some sense?

Comment: See also this similar (but a bit clearer) question: http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/6824/what-is-the-probability-of-breaking-the-aes-algorithm

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming there are holes in your question, but I'll answer it as is and then you'll probably want to change the question. Although please also see [this question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/6824/what-is-the-probability-of-breaking-aes-algorthim) as it might answer your question too.

The probability of decrypting an AES encrypted ciphertext is $1$ if you have the right key and (practically) $0$ if you have the wrong key. This is independent of rounds, key size, ciphertext length, padding, etc.