# Why doesn't CTR mode require blocking?

Tags: modes-of-operation, ctr

I've been reading a bit about block cipher modes and I have a relatively straightforward question regarding CTR.  In essence, I was hoping you guys would be kind enough to validate my understanding of things.

As I understand it, CTR does the following:

1. Take the first output of the nonce (let us assume an incrementing int for our purposes)
2. Encrypt the nonce with the key.  CTR requires that the key and the nonce be of identical size.
3. Perform some lossless operation between encrypted nonce and a portion of plaintext (e.g.:  XOR)
4. Increment nonce
5. Repeate *ad libitum*

Here's what I don't understand.  CTR is supposed to transform a block cipher into a stream cipher, but don't you still have to operate block-by-block for step 3?

What am I missing?

Comment: "CTR requires that the key and the nonce be of identical size" No. The nonce size corresponds to the block-size, but the key-size is completely independent. For example AES-256 has 128 bit blocks (and thus nonces) but a 256 bit key.

Comment: @CodesInChaos, When you say "block size", are you referring to the encryption of the nonce with the key?  In other words, for AES-256, we use two 128-bit nonces?  I'm afraid I don't follow...

Comment: The nonce is incremented as a counter and each counter is encrypted separately, which means each keystream block is independent of the other (you can jump to, say, the 3847th block by incrementing the initial counter by 3847 without having to compute any previous keystream blocks).

Comment: @blz With AES-256, we encrypt each 128-bit nonce with a 256-bit key. The block size of AES is 128 bits, in all variants. The key size varies between 128, 192, 256.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann, Right, I understand that AES-256 has a block size of 128 bits.  I also understand that we encrypt a 128-bit nonce with AES-256 (which has a 256-bit key, hence its name).  What I don't understand is how AES-256 applies 256-bits worth of key to a 128-bit-long block ... but perhaps this is outside of the scope of this question ;-)

Comment: Yeah, it is another question. Have a look at [my answer to a similar question](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/1527/58). Also have a look at [What is the effect of the different AES key lengths?](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/3615/58).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

While you do operate block-by-block when *generating* the pseudorandom stream, the actual encryption step (i.e., the XOR) is bitwise, and therefore does not require the message to be padded.

For example, the message "Hello" will be processed as follows (pseudocode):

```
byte stream[16] = AES(Key, Nonce);
byte plaintext[5]  = "Hello";
byte ciphertext[5];
for i from 0 to 5:
    ciphertext[i] = plaintext[i] XOR stream[i];
```

The remaining bytes of the pseudorandom stream, beyond the length of the message, are simply discarded.

Comment: Where this is most  useful is that you can keep appending encrypted data to the encrypted file, because there is no artificial padding on it.  You can also seek randomly into the file to get ciphertext.  The only issue with seeking is that you need to move the read ptr back enough to start on a block, and chop off that extra bit when giving plaintext range back to the user.