# What's the GCM-SHA 256 of a TLS protocol?

Tags: tls

If we read the Google line information about how the cypher the https communication, it reads:

```
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
```

I understand it's using ECDHE to exchange keys, using ECDSA as digital signature and making the symmetric encryption with AES algorithm, using 128 bit keys. I don't know though what the GCM_SHA256 means. What is that?

Comment: Probably answered in [this question](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/39590/whats-the-hash-for-in-ecdhe-rsa-aes-gcm-sha) on the security.SE.

Comment: @StephenTouset Upvoted comment (and created answer with similar comment). Better use the share button on any question you want to point to though. If the title changes your link may become obsolete.

Comment: @Maarten It doesn't matter if the title changes; the system ignores the title (like so: [http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/39590/this-isnt-the-real-title](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/39590/this-isnt-the-real-title)). It just looks at the ID.

Comment: Thanks cpast didn't know that. I'll make sure I spell my questions correctly :)

Comment: Also dupe https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/17691/why-does-aes-gcm-need-a-hash-mac-in-tls

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I'll quickly decompose this cipher suite.

1. `TLS` - standard starting point
2. `ECDHE` - elliptic curve version of the Diffie-Hellman key-exchange using ephemeral keys (/exponents), other values for this position include `RSA`, `DH` and `DHE`
3. `ECDSA` - signature algorithm, used to sign the key-exchange parameters, omitted for `RSA`, other values include `RSA`
4. `AES_128` - AES with a 128-bit key, `AES_256` would denote a 256-bit key, with GCM, only `AES`, `CAMELLIA` and `ARIA` are possible, with AES being clearly the most popular and widely deployed choice.
5. `GCM` - [Galois/Counter Mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois/Counter_Mode), a modern authenticated encryption with associated data (AEAD) mode of operation for blockciphers with 128-bit blocks.
6. `SHA256` - Secure Hash Algorithm (SHA)-256, the hash-function used as a basis for key-derivation from the master secret in the TLS protocol, as well as for authentication of the finished message. See [Maarten's answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/26434/23623) for more details.

Comment: actually, there are camellia and ARIA GCM cipher suites. AES is not the only cipher that works in GCM mode. gnutls supports camellia GCM cipher suites, and its not too difficult to add camellia GCM support to openssl (mostly copy+paste from the AES GCM code).

Comment: @lilywilson, thank you. I'll update the answer and emphasize that AES is the most common choice.

Comment: I'm sure that 6. is incorrect. Although the same hash function may also be used for the signature, I'm pretty sure that the acceptable hash algorithms are communicated differently (i.e. using extensions).

Comment: The kex and cert hash functions the client can use are communicated using extension. Tls 1.2 says symmetric keys are generated using prf which can be sha256 or sha384 or something else, as defined in the cipher suite.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes, yes you're right, I had this wrong in mind at the time I wrote the answer. I've updated it and linked to your answer for more details.

Comment: @Z.T., Indeed the ciphersuite is not used for the signature stuff. An extension is used for signature. I've updated my answer to be more appropriate now.

Answer (score 12):

In [TLS 1.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246) the `GCM` and `SHA-256` in `GCM_SHA256` should be seen separately.

GCM is the authenticated mode of operation used for confidentiality and integrity/authenticity of the messages (including the messages containing the data that TLS has been designed to protect).

SHA-256 is a parameter for the HMAC function which is used as PRF (pseudo random function) throughout the protocol.

> **5.  HMAC and the Pseudorandom Function**

> *The TLS record layer uses a keyed Message Authentication Code (MAC)
> to protect message integrity.*  The cipher suites defined in this
> document use a construction known as HMAC, described in [HMAC], which
> is based on a hash function.  Other cipher suites MAY define their
> own MAC constructions, if needed.

> In addition, a construction is required to do expansion of secrets
> into blocks of data *for the purposes of key generation or validation*.
> This pseudorandom function (PRF) takes as input a secret, a seed, and
> an identifying label and produces an output of arbitrary length.

> In this section, we define one PRF, based on HMAC.  This PRF with the
> SHA-256 hash function is used for all cipher suites defined in this
> document and in TLS documents published prior to this document when
> TLS 1.2 is negotiated.  *New cipher suites MUST explicitly specify a
> PRF and, in general, SHOULD use the TLS PRF with SHA-256 or a
> stronger standard hash function.*

Now because GCM already provides message integrity the HMAC / PRF construction is not needed for that purpose in the ciphersuite.

---

The HMAC based PRF is however used at other locations:

> **7.4.9 Finished**

> ...

> The Finished message is the first one protected with the just
> negotiated algorithms, keys, and secrets.  Recipients of Finished
> messages MUST verify that the contents are correct.  Once a side
> has sent its Finished message and received and validated the
> Finished message from its peer, it may begin to send and receive
> application data over the connection.

> ...

> ```
> verify_data
> ```

```
     PRF(master_secret, finished_label, Hash(handshake_messages))
        [0..verify_data_length-1];
```

... and ...

> **8.1.  Computing the Master Secret**

> For all key exchange methods, the same algorithm is used to convert
> the pre_master_secret into the master_secret.  The pre_master_secret
> should be deleted from memory once the master_secret has been
> computed.

> ```
>  master_secret = PRF(pre_master_secret, "master secret",
> ```

```
                      ClientHello.random + ServerHello.random)
                      [0..47];
```

Note that TLS 1.2 deviates from the previous versions with regards to this:

> **1.2.  Major Differences from TLS 1.1**

> - The MD5/SHA-1 combination in the pseudorandom function (PRF) has
>   been replaced with cipher-suite-specified PRFs.  All cipher suites
>   in this document use P_SHA256.

- The MD5/SHA-1 combination in the digitally-signed element has been
  replaced with a single hash.  *Signed elements now include a field
  that explicitly specifies the hash algorithm used.*

I've slanted the last sentence because it shows that the hash algorithm used for digital signatures used for authentication may very well differ from the once specified for the PRF in the ciphersuite.

Comment: great answer, do you have a src for this: "Now because GCM already provides message integrity the HMAC / PRF construction is not needed for that purpose in the ciphersuite."?

Comment: If it's just this sentence: "Other cipher suites MAY define their own MAC constructions, if needed.", I guess that means that GHASH is used for GCM?