# AES Inverse Key Schedule

Tags: aes, block-cipher, key-schedule

I have a 128-bit input-block and the corresponding cipher-block given.
Additionally I have the **last** round-key given. 
Is it now possible to get (calculate) the associated cipher-key? I already implemented the normal key-schedule with the rcon to generate the round-keys out of a cipher-key (like on wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rijndael_key_schedule), but it didn't help me much for the other way... 
Ist the AES Key Schedule easily invertible? I'm a bit baffled now because i thought it would be.

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: Duplicate of [Recovering plaintext from AES-128 given round key 10 and ciphertext](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/63917/18298)

Answer (score 10):

**Yes**, that is possible: It is quite obvious from the [description of the key schedule](https://samiam.org/key-schedule.html) that all involved operations are invertible. An implementation of that inversion is the function `aes128_key_schedule_inv_round` found in [this C file](https://web.archive.org/web/20190629185148/https://github.com/cmcqueen/aes-min/blob/master/aes-min.c#L393).

Comment: Wow, it's really that obvious...Big thanks for the helpful answer, altough it was a stupid question in hindsight.

Comment: @Tom Just because there is an easy answer doesn't mean that the question is stupid. It's actually a fine question. Don't forget to accept a winning answer.

Comment: @yyyyyyy The above link has become broken with the passage of time. Are you able to provide a redirect?

Comment: @KenGoss Thanks! I've updated the link.

Answer (score 8):

Yes. See the schema in [this answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/1527/553).

You are given $k_{43}, k_{42}, k_{41}, k_{40}$. So you can compute $k_{39}$ from $k_{43} = k_{42} \oplus k_{39}$ etc. Just follows the recursion backwards. There is only one unknown at every stage.

Comment: I've overlooked that there's really only one unknown at every stage. I was so convinced that there are two unknowns at first, that i couldn't think further. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Following the answer of @Henno Brandsma.

For AES-256:

---

$k_{56} = f(k_{55}) \oplus k_{48} \to k_{48} = f(k_{55}) \oplus k_{56}$

$k_{57} = k_{56} \oplus k_{49} \space\space\space\space\space\to k_{49} = k_{56}\oplus k_{57}$

$k_{58} = k_{57} \oplus k_{50} \space\space\space\space\space\to k_{50} = k_{57}\oplus k_{58}$

$k_{59} = k_{58} \oplus k_{51}  \space\space\space\space\space\to k_{51} = k_{58}\oplus k_{59}$

---

Note  that the function $f()$ does not change in the inverse key schedule .