# How does the round key work in AES 256

Tags: aes

Anyone can explaine to me how does the round key in aes256 work please, why is the round key 32 digit while 1 block only have 16 digit? how can 32 digit key XOR 16 digit block? Is it like two digit of round key XOR 1 digit in block?

Comment: Read the specifications. There are no "digits", maybe you mean bytes.

Comment: [Our Paŭlo Ebermann had a great drawing](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/20/what-are-the-practical-differences-between-256-bit-192-bit-and-128-bit-aes-enc/1527#1527). Actually start from [A Stick Figure Guide to the Advanced Encryption Standard (AES)](http://www.moserware.com/assets/stick-figure-guide-to-advanced/A%20Stick%20Figure%20Guide%20to%20the%20Advanced%20Encryption%20Standard%20%28AES%29.pdf)

Comment: I've voted to close this as a duplicate of your other question, they're very much related! In the mean time, you may incorporate this one into that one, and retract this one yourself. Finally, by the end of the day, no one explains better than the [spec](https://csrc.nist.gov/publications/detail/fips/197/final) itself (which itself had recently been updated for various reasons including readability). The only thing we can do, is to help clarify the arcane terminologies that you might not understand.